# Duplicar registro no banco de dados com novo id

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Tenho uma tabela no banco de dados chamada usuário, com **n** campos, como posso duplicar um determinado registro só que com um novo id?

```
insert into usuarios * select * from usuarios where id = x?
```

obs: este id é uma chave primária não-nula

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode fazer um `INSERT` `SELECT` ao mesmo tempo, assim:

```
INSERT INTO tabela (campo1, caompo2, ...) 
   SELECT campo1, caompo2, ... FROM tabela WHERE primary_key = 3;
```

Obs.:

- Você deve passar a mesma quantidade de campos no `insert` e no `select`.
- Não é obrigatório passar todos os campos da tabela, mas os campos de não passar ficam como `null`.
- Não precisa passar a chave primária para fazer a cópia do registro.

Caso queira copiar a linha sem especificar todos os campos, você pode fazer assim:

**Crie uma tabela temporária e associe a linha que queira copiar**

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE id = 3;
```

**Atualize a tabela `temp` com um novo `id`**

```
UPDATE tmp SET id_conta = 4 WHERE id_conta = 3;
```

**Agora, basta aplicar o `INSERT`**

```
INSERT INTO conta SELECT * FROM tmp WHERE id_conta = 4;
```

Comment: existe alguma forma de copiar todos os campos sem especificar eles?

Comment: Atualizei a resposta conforme especificou

Comment: a tabela tmp se apagaria sozinha depois? e os 3 comandos podem ser usados juntos?

Comment: TEMPORARY – indica que a tabela criada será temporária, o que significa que ela expira assim que a sua sessão no MySQL terminar

Comment: Como assim usar juntos? Executá-los juntos?

Comment: perdão, não tinha visto o comando temporary rs, falo dos 3 comandos, devo executar um de cada vez ou tem como executa-los numa "query" só?